# Using combos within a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

I having problems trying to get things to work with a BackgroundWorker.

I have a checkbox which when click I want to call the BackgroundWorkers RunWorkerAsync method:

```
    private void checkBoxLoadRecords_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

So within the DoWork event I call the SelectionChangeComitted event on one of my combos:

```
    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        comboSelectedIDs_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender, e);
    }
```

Within the SelectionChangeComitted method I receive an error on the first line where I try to retrieve the ID into a variable. The error I receive is: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'comboSelectedIDs' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

```
void comboSelectedIDs_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int idToUse = (int)multiSelectedIDs.SelectedValue; //Errors here!
    SetupNamesCombo(idToUse);
}
```

How do I get round this problem?

I think I'm going to have a similar problem when using my custom controls as they use the combos text value and I would like to get that in the BackgroundWorker.

I'm using C# 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: don't call event handler - create method and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dispatcher class to access to the UI elements from different threads:

```
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            int idToUse = (int)multiSelectedIDs.SelectedValue;
        });
```

Or if you are in a code behind file you can just do this without the `Deployment.Current`.

Comment: What namespace do I need to import to use this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, Deployment.Current.Dispathcer is in Silverlight. If you use WPF, then App.Current.Dispatcher...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access UI controls in any thread other than the UI thread.

One solution is to save the values of the UI controls in a separate POCO object, so you can access them from the background worker.